# SVN update command behaviour on internet failure

Tags: svn, working-copy

Suppose I am updating my local repository using svn update command and internet went down in between. What will happen to my local repository? Will it become unstable due to partially downloaded files?

Comment: Delete your local repo or do a clean checkout to another location and compare.  You can only lose the changes since the last commit.

Comment: Just run `svn update` and then press Ctrl-C to cancel the operation to see what is going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion does not have *local repositories*, it has [*working copies*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) that can be considered as your private workspace.

If the `svn update` operation gets interrupted you should run `svn cleanup` and `svn update` again. Read [SVNBook | Sometimes You Just Need to Clean Up](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cleanup.html).

Comment: Sorry..I just want to know what will happen to working copy if update got interrupted in between? It will become unstable due to partial download or partially downloaded files will get deleted and working copy will get restored to previous version?